# PHP: how to return counter of value from recursive function?

Tags: php, arrays

```
function count($array){ 

    $counter=0;
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){ 
    if(is_array($value)){ 
            count($value); 
        }else{
            if(strcmp($value, "Hi") == 0){
                $counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}

$arrays = array("Hi", "a", "Hi", "b", "c", array("c", "Hi", array("Hi"), "d"));
```

If I call `count($arrays);` I want to print 4 in this case.
But my code keeps printing 0.
It seems it does not return counter of "Hi" properly but I have no idea.

Comment: `count()` is a reserved function! And why you want to print 4?!?

Comment: @Rizier123: I guess because "Hi" is present 4 times in that array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count()` is a built-in function of PHP, better if you change the name:

```
function myRecursiveCount($array, $needle = "Hi"){ 
   $counter=0;
   foreach($array as $value){ 
     if(is_array($value)){ 
       $counter += myRecursiveCount($value); 
     } else if ($value === $needle){
       $counter++;  
     }
   }
   return $counter;
}

$inputs = array("Hi", "a", "Hi", "b", "c", array("c", "Hi", array("Hi"), "d"));
echo myRecursiveCount($inputs); // Prints 4
```

You need two edits:

- the function should return the `$counter`;
- in the recursive call you should append the result: `$counter += f();`.

I have also applied two optional improvements:

- you don't need to populate the variable `$key` as you don't need it
- to compare two strings you can simply use `==` comparison operator (`strcmp` feels so old)

Live on codepad: http://codepad.org/ATiKV09d

Comment: I guess `$counter += count($value);` should be `$counter += myRecursiveCount($value);`?